# Reactive Streams TCK (Technology Compatibility Kit) test on simple application stalls/slows will not run

Tags: java, maven, java-11, reactive-streams

***Question:***

```
Need help successfully running test from Reactive Streams TCK (Technology Compatibility Kit)?
```

***SimplePublisher.java (example)***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.jar;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import org.reactivestreams.FlowAdapters;

import java.util.concurrent.Flow;

public class SimplePublisher implements Flow.Publisher<Integer> {

    private final Iterator<Integer> iterator;

    SimplePublisher(int count) {
        this.iterator = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, count).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(Flow.Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
        iterator.forEachRemaining(subscriber::onNext);
        subscriber.onComplete();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimplePublisher(10).subscribe(new Flow.Subscriber<>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer item) {
                System.out.println("item = [" + item + "]");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("complete");
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

***...running "main()" method successfully runs producing the output predicted...***

```
item = [1]
item = [2]
item = [3]
item = [4]
item = [5]
item = [6]
item = [7]
item = [8]
item = [9]
item = [10]
complete
```

***SimplePublisherTest.java (test - fails to run, i.e., slows/hangs)***

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc.jar;

import java.util.concurrent.Flow;
import org.reactivestreams.tck.TestEnvironment;
import org.reactivestreams.tck.flow.FlowPublisherVerification;

//FlowPublisherVerification

public class SimplePublisherTest extends FlowPublisherVerification<Integer> {

    public SimplePublisherTest() {
        super(new TestEnvironment());
    }

    @Override
    public Flow.Publisher<Integer> createFlowPublisher(long elements) {
        return new SimplePublisher((int) elements);
    }

    @Override
    public Flow.Publisher<Integer> createFailedFlowPublisher() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

***output from the running the test***

```
--- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ sp ---
Deleting C:\tools\sp\target

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ sp ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\tools\sp\src\main\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ sp ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 1 source file to C:\tools\sp\target\classes

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ sp ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\tools\sp\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ sp ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 1 source file to C:\tools\sp\target\test-classes

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ sp ---
Surefire report directory: C:\tools\sp\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running aaa.bbb.ccc.jar.SimplePublisherTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNGMapConfigurator@123a439b

(test hangs at this point!)
```

***pom.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
    <artifactId>sp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>sp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams-flow-adapters</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams-tck-flow</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>        
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration> 
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>            

</project>
```

***example taken from...***

https://blog.softwaremill.com/how-not-to-use-reactive-streams-in-java-9-7a39ea9c2cb3

***Environment***

java 11

reactive-streams (v1.0.2)

reactive-streams-flow-adapters (v1.0.2)

reactive-streams-tck-flow (v1.0.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the answer was simply to add a maxElementsFromPublisher() method to the SimplePublisherTest.java class...

e.g.,

```
@Override
public long maxElementsFromPublisher() {
    return 1000;
}
```

---

***Found this info at this github page...***

https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm/tree/master/tck

*from readme.md...*

*In order to inform the TCK that the Publisher is only able to signal up to 2 elements, override the maxElementsFromPublisher method like this:*

```
@Override public long maxElementsFromPublisher() {
  return 2;
}
```

*The TCK also supports Publishers which are not able to signal completion. Imagine a Publisher being backed by a timer—such a Publisher does not have a natural way to "complete" after some number of ticks. It would be possible to implement a Processor which would "take n elements from the TickPublisher and then signal completion to the downstream", but this adds a layer of indirection between the TCK and the Publisher one initially wanted to test. It is suggested to test such unbouded Publishers either way—using a "TakeNElementsProcessor" or by informing the TCK that the Publisher is not able to signal completion. The TCK will then skip all tests which require onComplete signals to be emitted.*

*In order to inform the TCK that your Publiher is not able to signal completion, override the maxElementsFromPublisher method like this:*

```
@Override public long maxElementsFromPublisher() {
  return publisherUnableToSignalOnComplete(); // == Long.MAX_VALUE == unbounded
}
```